# Get specific of the logging providers from dependency injection container

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I have joined a project that has an API which uses packages that add Serilog to dependency injection container. Problem is for xyz reasons, I want to use NLog and once I add it to the container like so:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    }).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    }).UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
```

When I try to get ILogger from container by adding ILogger dependency, I actually get Serilog and not NLog instance. I want to know how I can get NLog and not Serilog

[image]

Comment: HM, remove serilog dependencies and add NLog nuget ?

Comment: I'm afraid I wouldn't want to do that now... Maybe in future...

Comment: are you loading your nlog.config file in the main method.?

Comment: Well currently I am using this everywhere I need the logger... private NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();